# PHP searching with XPath

Tags: php, xpath

I have the following content:

```
<div class="item">
<a href="ONE">
    <img src="TWO">
</a>
</div>
```

I want to use XPath to pull out "ONE" and "TWO" from there.

The code I have right now is:

```
$html = file_get_contents($_POST['url']);
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML ($html);
$selector = new DOMXPath($document);
$query = '//div[@class="item"]';
$anchors = $selector->query($query);
foreach ($anchors as $node) {
    // print ONE;
    // print TWO;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here comes an example:

```
$html = <<<EOF
<div class="item">
<a href="ONE">
  <img src="TWO">
</a>
</div>
EOF;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$selector = new DOMXPath($doc);

$links = $selector->query(
    '//div[@class="item"]//@href | //div[@class="item"]//@src'
);

foreach($links as $link) {
    echo $link->nodeValue . PHP_EOL;
}
```

If you want to break it down by `<div class="item">` you can use the following code:

```
foreach($selector->query('//div[@class="item"]') as $div) {
    foreach($selector->query('.//@href | .//@src', $div) as $link) {
        echo $link->nodeValue . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```